# Passing an undefined variable to a function and returning that variable with a value

Tags: python

So I am trying to pass in a variable to a function which is not yet defined. I want the function to assign this variable a new value and do something with it and then return this variable. Then I want to use that variable outside of the fuction since it should now be defined.
I realize this example is not the best because you can do the same thing by just creating a variable and adding 5 to it but I want to know if you can actually somehow do it like I tried it.

```
def age_in_5_years(person_age, age):
    person_age = value + 5
    return person_age

age_in_5_years(my_age, 20)
age_in_5_yearsr(dads_age, 50)

print(my_age) # expecting: >>>25
print(dads_age) # expecting: >>>55

# what I get >>> NameError: name 'my_age' is not defined
```

Comment: This is not how Python works. I highly suggest reading some more on datatypes, variables and functions.

Comment: You can't. Just return what you want, and explicitely assign the returned value.

Comment: You cannot pass an undefined variable to a function, full stop. How could something that doesn't exist be passed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot, but you can do this:

```py
def age_in_5_years(age):
    return age + 5

my_age = age_in_5_years(20)
dads_age = age_in_5_years(50)

print(my_age)
print(dads_age)
```

Comment: yeah that*s basically the exact same thing. I should have thought of this... Thanks a lot though!

Answer (score 0):

There is no point of doing this. You can resolve this problem like this:

```
def age_in_5_years(age):
    age += 5
    return age

my_age = age_in_5_years(20)
dads_age = age_in_5_yearsr(50)

print(my_age) # expecting: >>>25
print(dads_age) # expecting: >>>55
```